# Knockout.js enable save only if value change

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a simple html page with value input and save button.
I want the save will be enabled only if the value is changed (somtimes is initialized and somtimes not.

I've tryied few things without any success

HTML

```
<input type="text"
    placeholder="type here"
    data-bind="value: rate,"/>
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

JS

```
    var viewmodel = function () {
        this.rate = ko.observable('88').extend(required: true);
    };

    viewmodel.prototype.save = function () {
        alert('save should be possible only if rate is changed);
    };
```

Also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/israel_1986/xhLrB/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout js - Dirty Flag issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014040/knockout-js-dirty-flag-issue)

Comment: Check this link too - http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: I thought might be something simplest for only one box...

Comment: Here is another example that is an extender that may work bettter for you - http://schinckel.net/2012/01/14/knockoutjs-dirty-extender./

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to achieve this with a computed observable and the `enable` binding.
See http://jsfiddle.net/brendonparker/xhLrB/1/

Javascript:

```
var ctor = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.originalRate = '88';
    self.rate = ko.observable('');
    self.canSave = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.originalRate == self.rate();
    });
};

ctor.prototype.save = function () {
    alert('save should be possible only if rate is changed');
};

ko.applyBindings(new ctor());
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type here" data-bind="value: rate, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
<button data-bind="click: save, enable: canSave">Save</button>
```